# Can you help me with maximizing my image background?

Tags: javascript, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ0et.jpg)

I'm using this the document.style

```
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('okeball-HD.png')";
  document.body.style.backgroundPosition = '100% 100%';
  document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
  document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Carlo: If you have a solution, you should accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tricks show you how to do this:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

There's a few different ways you can do this.

Set a div for the image:

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="okeball-HD.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Then set the style:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```